# CompletableFuture, supplyAsync() and thenApply()

Tags: multithreading, java-8, concurrency, completable-future, futuretask

Need to confirm something. The following code:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {return doSomethingAndReturnA();})
    .thenApply(a -> convertToB(a));
```

would be the same as:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(() -> {
        A a = doSomethingAndReturnA();
        convertToB(a);
 });
```

Right?

Furthermore, another two questions following as for "is there any reason why we would use `thenApply`?"

1) having big code for conversion?

**or**

2)  need to reuse the lambda block in other places?

Comment: Check this article. Very well explained: http://codeflex.co/java-multithreading-completablefuture-explained/

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It is *not the same thing*. In the second example where `thenApply` is not used it is certain that the call to `convertToB` is executed in the same thread as the method `doSomethingAndReturnA`.

But, in the first example when the `thenApply` method is used other things can happen.

First of all, if the `CompletableFuture` that executes the `doSomethingAndReturnA` has completed, the invocation of the `thenApply` will happen in the caller thread. If the `CompletableFutures` hasn't been completed the `Function` passed to `thenApply` will be invoked in the same thread as `doSomethingAndReturnA`.

Confusing? Well [this article might be helpful](http://blog.krecan.net/2013/12/25/completablefutures-why-to-use-async-methods/) (thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis for the link).

I have provided a short example that illustrates how `thenApply` works.

```
public class CompletableTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final CompletableFuture<Integer> future = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> doSomethingAndReturnA())
                .thenApply(a -> convertToB(a));

        future.get();
    }

    private static int convertToB(final String a) {
        System.out.println("convertToB: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Integer.parseInt(a);
    }

    private static String doSomethingAndReturnA() {
        System.out.println("doSomethingAndReturnA: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "1";
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
doSomethingAndReturnA: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
convertToB: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
```

So, when the first operation is slow (i.e. the `CompletableFuture` is not yet completed) both calls occur in the same thread. But if the we were to remove the `Thread.sleep`-call from the `doSomethingAndReturnA` the output (may) be like this:

```
doSomethingAndReturnA: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
convertToB: main
```

Note that `convertToB` call is in the `main` thread.

Comment: This answer and this post (http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture/) help me to understand CompletableFuture

Comment: This still doesn't explain why one would use `thenApply`?

Comment: In the first case, does ```ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1``` just hang there and wait until ```doSomethingAndReturnA``` returns?

Comment: @Yamcha, if you use the supplyAsync+thenApply combo, the main function is free to move onto other tasks and doesn't have to wait. A separate thread does the waiting.

Comment: When `doSomethingAndReturnA()` takes some time like sleep or api call, both the mentioned scenarios in question are same?

Answer (score 3):

`thenApply()` is a callback function, which will be executed when `supplyAsync()` return a value.

In code snippet 2, the thread which invoked `doSomethingAndReturnA()` waits for the function to get executed and return the data.

But in some exceptional cases (like making Webservice call and waiting for response), the thread has to wait for **long** time to get the response, which badly consumes lot of system computation resources (just waiting for response).

To avoid that, `CompletableFuture` comes with **callback** feature, where once the `doSomethingAndReturnA()` is invoked, a separate thread will take care of executing `doSomethingAndReturnA()` and the main caller thread will continue to do other operations without waiting for the response to return.

Once the response of `doSomethingAndReturnA` is available, the call back method will be invoked (i.e., `thenApply()`)