# How to make a future dependent on two others in Java

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a future that would ideally take two parameters coming from two other futures. For this I have .thenCombine(), the trick here is that the second future needs the result of the first one.

Let's say:

- I have futures A, B and C
- Future B needs the result of future A
- Future C needs the result of future A and B

I would like to have something like:

```
CompletableFuture<Customer> customerFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> findCustomer(123));
CompletableFuture<Shop> shopFuture         = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync((customer) ->getAllAccessibleShops(customer));
CompletableFuture<Route> routeFuture       = customerFuture.thenCombine(shopFuture, (cust, shop) -> findRoute(cust, shop));
```

Of course thenCombine() is not what I'm looking for and the code above looks dumb because I shouldn't need the customer afterwards, but this is only an example.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If the steps have to be done sequentially why are they in separate Futures?

Comment: @jimmycarr could you elaborate on this? I'm really interested

Comment: The point of a future is to do some processing in the background and then allow you to get the result later on. If future's B and C depend on the other Futures before them, then putting it all in one future is just as quick as putting it in three separate Futures which all depend on each other.

Comment: Okay I understand, makes sense. So I suppose I will change the way I do this. Now just out of curiosity, is there something that could make it work anyway? I mean having this sequential dependency?

Comment: Yes you can make it work the way you originally had in mind. If you call [Future.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) on each of the futures you can wait for it to finish processing and get the result which can then be passed into the constructor of the next future.

Comment: Okay, now I really see why this is broken. Doing the .get() just breaks the overall idea. Thanks for the light!

Comment: You do not need to call `.get()`, and in most cases you should not call it when using `CompletableFuture`. Your usage of `thenCombine()` is fine, the only problem in your code is in the creation of `shopFuture`. You should use `thenApply[Async]()` for that. Of course their execution will be sequential, but maybe there is additional processing you would like to do with the result of A or B that could be performed in parallel to B or C, and then this would become more useful.

Comment: Oh, I see, like have `A, B=A.thenApply((x) -> {}) and C = A.thenCombine(B, (x,y) -> {})` ?

Comment: Yes, so it's almost what you did. Do you want I post it as an answer? (you should @mention people so they get notifications, otherwise only the OP is notified)

Comment: oh sorry @DidierL I didn't know this. Yes can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, the only issue is in the declaration of `shopFuture`. You should use `thenApply[Async]()` so that it can access the result of the first one:

```
CompletableFuture<Customer> customerFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> findCustomer(123));
CompletableFuture<Shop> shopFuture         = customerFuture.thenApply((customer) -> getAllAccessibleShops(customer));
CompletableFuture<Route> routeFuture       = customerFuture.thenCombine(shopFuture, (cust, shop) -> findRoute(cust, shop));
```

Note that the execution order remains sequential since `shopFuture` requires the result of `customerFuture`, and `routeFuture` requires the result of `shopFuture`. However if you have additional work to do with the `Customer` or the `Shop`, you could use additional `thenApply[Async]` calls to run them.

If you don't have anything to do with those results, you might want to group all the 3 calls into a single `supplyAsync()`:

```
CompletableFuture<Route> customerFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
   Customer customer = findCustomer(123));
   Shop shop = getAllAccessibleShops(customer));
   return findRoute(customer, shop)
});
```

See also [CompletableFuture, supplyAsync() and thenApply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723546/completablefuture-supplyasync-and-thenapply) for the difference in behaviour between the two.