# Need detailed explanation for supplyAsync and whenComplete methods of CompletableFuture under the hood

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, threadpool, completable-future

I'm looking JAVA API docs for CompletableFuture, where I've come across with this particular line,

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.
>
> Refer link description (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

**I have confusion for this specific phrase: "or by any other caller of a completion method"**

**Q1) What does this actually mean? Due to this, I doubt that whenComplete will execute the same thread or there can be chances to be in the different thread?**

I've used CompletableFuture with its supplyAsync()/runAsync() and whenComplete() methods.()

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> {DO_SOMETHING}, myExecutor
).whenComplete((result, exception) -> {DO_SOMETHING});
```

For supplyAsync()/runAsync(), I've used the Executor service. After that, the result of that method (supplyAsync/runAsync) will dive into whenComplete() method.

So the question is: **Q2) whenComplete will ALWAYS use the same thread which is used by supplyAsync/runAsync after immediate?**

(If whenComplete() method execute in the same thread which is initiated from my Executor at the time of supplyAsync()/runAsync() method.)

Comment: I checked these links but still I want to make sure about whenComplete. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723546/completablefuture-supplyasync-and-thenapply and https://blog.krecan.net/2013/12/25/completablefutures-why-to-use-async-methods/

Comment: specification reads "may", so you cannot assume "always".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In which thread does CompletableFuture's completion handlers execute in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060438/in-which-thread-does-completablefutures-completion-handlers-execute-in)